# tikz-feynman diagrams inside align* environment produce an error

Tags: align, tikz-feynman

I'm trying to typeset an equation in which there are a lot of Feynman diagrams, which I draw with `tikz-feynman`, as in the example I pasted below.
When I compile, it halts at the first `tikzpicture`, with the following error:

```
Runaway argument?
 &= \begin {tikzpicture}[scale=0.64,baseline=(o)] \begin {feynman}[in\ETC.
! Paragraph ended before \align* was complete.
<to be read again> 
\par 
l.17
```

I tried with `pdflatex` and `lualatex`, with no differences between the two.
If instead of the `align*` environment I use an `equation*` and `aligned` combination, it works without any problem.
However I'd like to use `align*` since the equation is very long (I shortened it as much as possible in the MWE below) and this way I'm able to break the equation in different pages with `\allowdisplaybreaks`.

I also tried using simple `tikzpicture`s such as just some circles, without anything from `tikz-feynman`, and it doesn't throw any error.

Where does the problem lie? Can I draw Feynman diagrams inside an `align` environment, and how?

```
\documentclass[10pt,b5paper]{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tikz-feynman}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
    &=
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.64,baseline=(o)]
        \begin{feynman}[inline=(o)]
            \path (-1,0) -- (3,2);
            \vertex [empty dot, minimum size=0mm] (o) at (1,1) {};
            \vertex [dot, label=180:$x$]   (x)  at (0,0) {};
            \vertex [dot, label=0:$x'$]    (y)  at (2,0) {};
            \vertex [dot, label=180:$x_1$] (x1) at (0,2) {};
            \vertex [dot, label=0:$x_2$]   (x2) at (2,2) {};

            \diagram*{
                (x1) -- [fermion, half left, out=25, in=155] (x2)
                -- [fermion, half left, out=25, in=155] (x1),
                (x1) -- [photon] (x2),
            };
            \draw (x) arc [start angle=180, end angle=-180, radius=3.5mm];
            \draw (y) arc [start angle=0, end angle=360, radius=3.5mm];
        \end{feynman}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    -
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.64,baseline=(o)]
        \begin{feynman}[inline=(o)]
            \path (-1,0) -- (3,2);
            \vertex [empty dot, minimum size=0mm] (o) at (1,1) {};
            \vertex [dot]   (x)  at (0,0) {};
            \vertex [dot]    (y)  at (2,0) {};
            \vertex [dot] (x1) at (0,2) {};
            \vertex [dot]   (x2) at (2,2) {};

            \diagram*{
                (x1) -- [fermion, half left, out=25, in=155] (x2)
                -- (o)
                -- [fermion] (x)
                -- [fermion] (y)
                -- (o)
                -- [fermion] (x1),
                (x1) -- [photon] (x2),
            };
            \draw [-, line width=2mm, white] (o)++(-2mm,-2mm) -- ++(4mm,4mm);
            \draw [-, black] (o)++(-2mm,-2mm) -- ++(4mm,4mm);

        \end{feynman}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    +\\[2mm] &
    -
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.64,baseline=(o)]
        \begin{feynman}[inline=(o)]
            \path (-1,0) -- (3,2);
            \vertex [empty dot, minimum size=0mm] (o) at (1,1) {};
            \vertex [dot]   (x)  at (0,0) {};
            \vertex [dot]    (y)  at (2,0) {};
            \vertex [dot] (x1) at (0,2) {};
            \vertex [dot]   (x2) at (2,2) {};

            \diagram*{
                (x1) -- [fermion, half left, out=25, in=155] (x2)
                -- [fermion] (y)
                -- [fermion] (x)
                -- [fermion] (x1),
                (x1) -- [photon] (x2),
            };
        \end{feynman}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    -
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.64,baseline=(o)]
        \begin{feynman}[inline=(o)]
            \path (-1,0) -- (3,2);
            \vertex [empty dot, minimum size=0mm] (o) at (1,1) {};
            \vertex [dot]   (x)  at (0,0) {};
            \vertex [dot]    (y)  at (2,0) {};
            \vertex [dot] (x1) at (0,2) {};
            \vertex [dot]   (x2) at (2,2) {};

            \diagram*{
                (x) -- [fermion, half left, out=25, in=155] (y)
                -- [fermion, half left, out=25, in=155] (x),
                (x1) -- [photon] (x2),
            };
            \draw (x1) arc [start angle=0, end angle=360, radius=3.5mm];
            \draw (x2) arc [start angle=180, end angle=-180, radius=3.5mm];
        \end{feynman}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Don't you have a blank line somewhere?

Comment: I do. I never thought they were a problem. I'll try removing them.

Comment: I don't think it's a problem if it's inside a `tikzpicture` environment, but there may be one if it's in mathematical part of your code.

Comment: @Bernard Seems it is a problem also inside a `tikzpicture`, after removing them the code works fine.

Comment: @Bernard That's what I was thinking either, and I was careful not to leave any... but it appears that blank lines inside `tikzpicture`s are bad, too! I removed them and now it works. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Bernard -- it there's not already a question that could be considered a duplicate, this seems worth an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After the O.P. and @Torbjørn T. experimented, it appears the `tikzpicture` environment is not blank lines-friendly when it is nested in equations.

Equations, whether multiline or not, don't like blank lines, don't like blank lines, and they don't like them even if they're nested in a `tikzpicture`.

However, if you use blank lines  an `aligned` environment nested in `equation(*)`, it *will* compile smoothly.

Comment: I don't think it's a problem with `tikzpicture` itself, since I always used blank lines in this environment and I never had a problem (switching from `align` to `equation` + `aligned` "solves" the problem, in fact), but with the `align` environment. Apparently there cannot be a blank line anywhere inside it, not even in nested environments.

Comment: OK, I'll modify my answer, as it may be useful to others.